# Image enhancement using software or a programming language (trying to assist a hit and run victim)

Tags: image, image-processing

My apologies for the "unorthodox" title and question, but I am interested in helping an 8 year old hit and run victim. An image of the fleeing car was captured on video and I do have access to a blurry still frame. I have tried in vain to enhance the image of the license plate and I was hoping some of us might be able to offer assistance.

Video:
http://www.cbs5az.com/clip/12271807/video-shows-car-hitting-boy-in-tempe-police-seek-driver

Image:
[image: img1]
<sub>(source: [abc15.com](http://media2.abc15.com/photo/2016/03/08/16x9/Little_boy_hurt_in_shocking_hit_and_run__0_33351314_ver1.0_640_480.jpg))</sub>

[image: img2]
<sub>(source: [worldnow.com](http://meredithaz.images.worldnow.com/images/10053496_G.jpg))</sub>

If you have a detailed knowledge of software capable of image enhancement, e.g. Photoshop, could you please try to enhance the license plate on the car seen in the above two images? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, if you can't make out the license plate numbers by zooming in on the available image, then a computer isn't going to be able to magically make out what it says either. A blur is a blur.

Comment: I think a logical assumption would be that image enhancement algorithms are available and in common use. NASA, The Jet Propulsion Lab, medical imaging facilities, etc.

Comment: I seriously doubt it. The data available is exactly what you see. A computer can't extract anything from an image that isn't there. If the image was blurry, but not too blurry, than a computer might be able to determine that something was a specific letter, but I think that image is just too blurry.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is integrating the plate image from all the frames of video but the quality is really poor so I would not expect much from it. For that you will need the video in some manageable form (like avi). May be the original file would be better. That video link is most likely post processed by augmented reality software and reencoded loosing quality even further.